# Yii2 afterFind() on multiple results

Tags: yii2

I need to perform some work after records are found, but the action needs only be performed once, rather than on every result.

Is there an equivalent to calling afterFind() that is called on the Query rather than on the ActiveRecord or am I missing something conceptually?

Comment: Why not find the records and after that do your work on them? If you need to do it once anyways....

Comment: @user2831723 because I need this in many places and I don't want to do this manually on every query.

Comment: Well it depends what exactly you want to do, but I would say that you are approaching it incorrectly. For example query your data and after that run it through some static method that you add to your model?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.

Instead of overriding `afterFind()`, I decided to do the extra work in `find()`.